# Merging Two Different csv files(data) into one file in SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssis

I have a situation right here: I created the table below:

```
CREATE TABLE temp1
(
ProcessName varchar(50),
ProcessNo  varchar(50),
ProcessPages varchar(50),
ProcessClass varchar (50)
)

INSERT INTO temp1 VALUES ('PRO1','PR012','5','O');
INSERT INTO temp1 VALUES ('PRO1','PR012','4','Y');
INSERT INTO temp1 VALUES ('PRO1','PR012','10','Y');
INSERT INTO temp1 VALUES ('PRO1','PR012','7','Y');
INSERT INTO temp1 VALUES ('PRO1','PR012','6','Y');
INSERT INTO temp1 VALUES ('PRO1','PR012','14','K');
INSERT INTO temp1 VALUES ('PRO1','PR012','23','Y');
INSERT INTO temp1 VALUES ('PRO1','PR012','45','L');
INSERT INTO temp1 VALUES ('PRO1','PR012','52','Y');
INSERT INTO temp1 VALUES ('PRO2','PR022','3','K');
INSERT INTO temp1 VALUES ('PRO2','PR022','5','T');
INSERT INTO temp1 VALUES ('PRO2','PR022','6','Y');
INSERT INTO temp1 VALUES ('PRO2','PR022','5','Y');
INSERT INTO temp1 VALUES ('PRO2','PR022','5','H');
INSERT INTO temp1 VALUES ('PRO2','PR022','8','Y');
INSERT INTO temp1 VALUES ('PRO2','PR022','5','T');
INSERT INTO temp1 VALUES ('PRO2','PR022','2','Y');
INSERT INTO temp1 VALUES ('PRO2','PR022','3','T');
INSERT INTO temp1 VALUES ('PRO2','PR022','3','Y');
INSERT INTO temp1 VALUES ('PRO3','PR032','5','Y');
INSERT INTO temp1 VALUES ('PRO3','PR032','10','Y');
INSERT INTO temp1 VALUES ('PRO3','PR032','15','Y');
INSERT INTO temp1 VALUES ('PRO3','PR032','25','Y');
INSERT INTO temp1 VALUES ('PRO3','PR032','35','Y');
INSERT INTO temp1 VALUES ('PRO3','PR032','45','Y');
INSERT INTO temp1 VALUES ('PRO3','PR032','55','Y');
INSERT INTO temp1 VALUES ('PRO3','PR032','25','Y');
INSERT INTO temp1 VALUES ('PRO3','PR032','25','Y');
INSERT INTO temp1 VALUES ('PRO3','PR032','20','Y');
INSERT INTO temp1 VALUES ('PRO3','PR032','3','O');
INSERT INTO temp1 VALUES ('PRO3','PR032','3','K');
```

Here is what I am trying to do in SSIS: I am trying to merge these two data sources

```
   ----First Data Source
    DECLARE @ColumnNames NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SELECT @ColumnNames=Stuff((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + Quotename(ProcessName)
                       FROM [temp1]
                       FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
    SET @SQL= '
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT [ProcessName], 
            COUNT(CASE WHEN ProcessPages >=  1 and ProcessPages <=  5 THEN ''1p'' END) AS [1p],
            COUNT(CASE WHEN ProcessPages >=  6 and ProcessPages <= 10 THEN ''2p'' END) AS [2p],
            COUNT(CASE WHEN ProcessPages >= 11 and ProcessPages <= 16 THEN ''3p'' END) AS [3p],
            COUNT(CASE WHEN ProcessPages >= 17 and ProcessPages <= 50 THEN ''4p'' END) AS [4p],
            COUNT(CASE WHEN ProcessPages >  50 THEN ''5p'' END) AS [5p],
            COUNT([ProcessName]) AS Total
        FROM temp1
        GROUP BY [ProcessName]) AS SOURCE
        UNPIVOT ( val FOR Process_No_In_Cases IN ([1p],[2p],[3p],[4p],[5p],[Total]) ) U
        PIVOT ( MAX(val) FOR ProcessName IN('+@ColumnNames +') ) As PivotTable'
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL


    ------Second Data Source
    DECLARE @ColumnNames2 NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @SQL2 NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SELECT @ColumnNames2=Stuff((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + Quotename([ProcessName])
                       FROM temp1
                       FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
    SET @SQL2= '
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT [ProcessName], 
            COUNT(CASE WHEN [ProcessClass]=''Y'' THEN ''Coordinated'' END) AS [Coordinated],
            COUNT([ProcessName]) AS Total
        FROM temp1
        GROUP BY [ProcessName]) AS SOURCE
        UNPIVOT ( val FOR [''] IN ([Coordinated],[Total]) ) U
        PIVOT ( MAX(val) FOR [ProcessName] IN('+@ColumnNames2 +') ) As PivotTable'

    --print @sql
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL2
```

And combine the output into one csv file like this:

```
Process_No_In_Cases PRO1    PRO2    PRO3
1p                   2       8        3
2p                   3       2        1
3p                   1       0        1
4p                   2       0        6
5p                   1       0        1
Total                9       10       12


Coordinated          6       5        10
Total                9       10       12
```

Any input?

--------Here is an updated:

With the same table temp1:

I have this two queries:

```
SELECT  *
 FROM (
    SELECT [ProcessName], 
        COUNT(CASE WHEN [ProcessPages] >=  1 and [ProcessPages] <=  5 THEN '1p' END) AS [1p],
        COUNT(CASE WHEN [ProcessPages] >=  6 and [ProcessPages] <= 10 THEN '2p' END) AS [2p],
        COUNT(CASE WHEN [ProcessPages] >= 11 and [ProcessPages] <= 16 THEN '3p' END) AS [3p],
        COUNT(CASE WHEN [ProcessPages] >= 17 and [ProcessPages] <= 50 THEN '4p' END) AS [4p],
        COUNT(CASE WHEN [ProcessPages] >  50 THEN '5p' END) AS [5p],
        COUNT([ProcessName]) AS Total
    FROM temp1
    GROUP BY [ProcessName]) AS SOURCE
    UNPIVOT ( val FOR [Pro_No_In_Cases] IN ([1p],[2p],[3p],[4p],[5p],[Total]) ) U
    PIVOT ( MAX(val) FOR [ProcessName] IN ([PRO1],[PRO2],[PRO3] 
            ) ) As PivotTable
```

--and

```
WITH CTE_Temp AS (
    SELECT 
       [ProcessName] =    
       CASE 
          WHEN [ProcessPages] >=  1 AND [ProcessPages] <=  5 THEN '1p'
          WHEN [ProcessPages] >=  6 AND [ProcessPages] <= 10 THEN '2p'
          WHEN [ProcessPages] >= 11 AND [ProcessPages] <= 16 THEN '3p'
          WHEN [ProcessPages] >= 17 AND [ProcessPages] <= 50 THEN '4p'
          WHEN [ProcessPages] >  50   THEN '5p'
       END
       , [ProcessClass]    
    FROM temp1
)
SELECT
    [ProcessName] = CASE WHEN GROUPING([ProcessName]) = 0 THEN [ProcessName] ELSE 'Total' END 
    , Coordinated     = COUNT(CASE WHEN [ProcessClass]  =  'Y' THEN [ProcessClass]  END)
    , Uncordinated = COUNT(CASE WHEN [ProcessClass]  <> 'Y' THEN [ProcessClass]  END)
FROM CTE_Temp
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ([ProcessName], ())
```

With SSIS, I placed them in two separate oledb sources and used a union all but it DIDN'T work.  How do I merge this tow sources to be on one csv(file) with spaces between them. Please see my new example:

```
Pro_No_In_cases PRO1    PRO2    PRO3    
1p               2       8       3  
2p               3       2       1  
3p               1       0       1  
4p               2       0       6  
5p               1       0       1  
Total            9       10      12 



 ProcessName    Coordinated Uncordinated    
   1p               5          8    
   2p               6          0    
   3p               1          1    
   4p               7          1    
   5p               2          0    
   Total            21         10
```

Any input?

Comment: I don't see any SSIS I only see T-SQL. I also don't see what your exact problem is. Do you get any error? Is your output not correct?

Comment: I am asking for how to combine this kind of files in SSIS. I have those two files i separate flat file connections. My question is how do i make thise files into one piece like above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Solution 
with SQL you can try to add 1-2-3 empty record between the 2 dataset and write. query 1 Union null record Union query 2

put the first querycode, in an OLEDB SOURCE chosing select data from query

 put the second querycode, in an another OLEDB SOURCE select data from query.

now use an Union, and connect the OLEDB to the Union.

see this, http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7257.ssis-union-all-transformation.aspx

now you have one datasource

Comment: Thanks for getting back but if you pay attention to my the two oledb sources, they do have the same column. Union will work for situation when two sources share the same column.

Comment: try to create just the first flow (that part of the output), after you did it, you use Union and add the combined record.
however Union can unify different column, you just Need to map the column

Comment: "do" or "don't" have the same columns? It's actually not clear from your explanation that they do or don't. All of your sample data has the same columns then you have a chunk of dynamic SQL in the middle

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid: They do not have the same column. If you run those two quries (assuming you created the temp 1 table and inserted those values), you will realize that their output are different. All I want to do is to achieve the above output in a csv format. Make sense?

Comment: sy but for me, the Output is equal. yes there are different Information, but the number and the type is equal

Comment: @MattiaCaputo: I have updated my post. Please check out my query and see what I mean. Union All didnt work.

Comment: in this case i think you Need to use vba script

Comment: @MattiaCaputo: I am not vast in VB. Can I get some examples on how to do this ?

Comment: i'm not strong with VB.  with SQL you can try to add 1-2-3 empty record between the 2 dataset and write.
query 1 Union null record Union query 2